# Mismatch slf4j version with Tomcat and WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, gradle, slf4j

I'm having the following error when I try to deploy my application on Tomcat.

```
04-Sep-2013 17:59:29.424 SEVERE [AsyncFileHandlerWriter-1626573634] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5370)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/springframework/instrument/classloading/tomcat/TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type LoggerFactory; used in the signature
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:299)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.context.AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.<init>(AbstractContextLoaderInitializer.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.<init>(AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.java:40)
    at com.bravofly.wfcobrand.configuration.web.ServletConfiguration.<init>(ServletConfiguration.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:162)
    ... 13 more
```

I've already found out the problem is in the libraries present in the lib directory: slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar.

Putting in there `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1` and `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.1` solved my problem.

I was wondering if is possible to do something in my app to solve the problem. I'm using gradle so I put:

```
  compile ... other dependencies
          "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.1",
          "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.1"
```

But this did not solve the problem. Is there a way to give a priority to the library defined on my build file?

Comment: PS: I know that Tomcat gives priority to the libraries in my webapp to load them, but I got the same error so I'm guessing there is some kind of problem when it comes to different version of the same library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not still sure why, it was the servlet container that had in the shared lib directory an older version for another project. So when we removed it everything worked fine.

We are using Tomcat 7 and I believed the app libs had priority but apparently if a version of it is already loaded it was discarding ours.